# Is the wattage important when buying a replacement solder tip?

Tags: soldering

I have a Weller SP15N (15 watt) soldering iron which needs a replacement tip. It needs 3.5mm tips.

Replacement tips on ebay often come with what looks like a wattage rating.

Why do tips come with wattage ratings, and is that rating a max. rating? In other words, can I use a 30 watt solder tip for my 15 watt soldering iron?

Comment: Is tyre size important when buying replacement tyres? I've got 15 inch rims I think I'll put 18 inch tyres on them! If you want your soldering iron to work at the proper temperature then you should fit it with the correct bit, not something designed to require twice the power.

Comment: No need to be sarcastic @PeterJennings; it was a sincere question. I asked the question here because I'm a novice and I know this is the place to find knowledgeable people! I would certainly not buy 18" tyres for 15" rims, just like I would not buy 4mm tips for a 3.5mm iron. However - to play along with your analogy -  are you absolutely certain about all aspects of regulations concerning tread depth, studded tyres or at what times you may not use summer tyres...or would you ask someone if you were in doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Weller indicate a wattage rating with their tips? I do not think they do.

The heating element has a power rating, this heating element sits in the "iron". For this type of soldering iron, the tip you can replace does not have a heating element. The tip is just a piece of metal (with some coating).

Weller will just indicate if a tip is suitable for your iron. If you want to be guaranteed good operation, get the original Weller tips.

If you want to save a few $$ you can try the replacement tips, even if the wattage doesn't match, it will not damage your iron.

So yes, you can safely ignore the wattage rating, if the tip fits and works that's fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to find original Weller tips, but local / national stores either do not have them or charge 30+ USD for a replacement tip. Same on eBay, 30+ USD for tip + shipping. So I started looking for a replacement based on dimension (3.5mm), but came across the wattage rating...

Comment: In other words...the power rating for a tip with no heater inside is just a limit for the max it can handle, while for a tip with a heating element it is how much power it will actually try to draw from the iron.